# Monotouch binding - "Cannot cast from source type to destination type."

Tags: binding, xamarin.ios

I am a newbie on Monotouch.  Recently, I am working on a Monotouch binding project that binds a custom iOS framework that developed myself into a .NET framework library.  I follow the instructions on Xamarin but currently I am having an issue that cannot be resolved.  This is my code.

```
**HEADER FILE IN OBJECTIVE C**

*GRG.h*
@interface GRG: NSObject {} 

// Shared instance 
+ (GRG*) sharedG; 

// Preference class 
@property (nonatomic, readonly) GRGPreferences  *preferences; 

// Driver version 
@property (readonly,copy) NSString* driverVersion; 

// More parameters... 
@end 

*GRGPreferences.h*
@interface GRGPreferences : NSObject <GRGPreferencesProtocol>{} 

// Enable DEBUG 
@property BOOL debugEnabled; 

// More parameters... 
@end 

*GRGPreferencesProtocol.h*
@protocol GRGPreferencesProtocol <NSObject>  

// More parameters... 
@end
```

I convert my header file into this

```
**API DEFINITION**

[BaseType (typeof (NSObject))] 
interface GRG 
{ 
        [Static][Export("sharedG")] 
        GRG SharedG{ get; } 

        [Export("preferences")] 
        GRGPreferences Preferences{ get;} 

        [Export("driverVersion", ArgumentSemantic.Copy)] 
        string DriverVersion {get;} 
} 

[BaseType (typeof (GRGPreferencesProtocol))] 
public interface GRGPreferences 
{ 
        [Export("debugEnabled")] 
        bool DebugEnabled{ get; set;} 
} 

[BaseType(typeof (NSObject))] 
[Model] 
public interface GRGPreferencesProtocol 
{}
```

After that, I created a test app on mono to test the newly created library and get access to the values I created.  However, I got an error.

> Console.WriteLine(GRG.sharedG.DriverVersion); 
>    - This works fine.  It returns the proper value.
>
> GRGPreferences pref = GRG.SharedG.Preferences; 
>    - Error : "Cannot cast from source type to destination type."
>
> Console.WriteLine(GRG.sharedG.Preferences.DebugEnabled); 
>    - Error : "Cannot cast from source type to destination type."

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm having a very similar problem (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16906955/binding-a-return-type-that-conforms-to-a-protocol)

Answer (score 1):

From a quick look I think this is what you want:

```
[BaseType (typeof (NSObject))] 
public interface GRGPreferences : GRGPreferencesProtocol {
```

Your `GRGPreferences` type inherits from `NSObject` while implementing the protocol you want.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  Unforunately it does not work.  I remove the linkage between GRGPrefencesProtocol so GRGPreferences is just a NSObject but it still does not work.  Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Please update your original question with your latest sources/definitions and I'll have a second look.

Comment: Hello poupou I just update my code below can you please have a look?