# Binding a return type that conforms to a protocol

Tags: xamarin.ios

I'm working with the ArcGIS Runtime for iOS, and I'm trying to set up a binding for some things that I'm doing. Here are the classes I'm trying to bind:

```
@interface AGSTiledLayer : AGSLayer {
 @private
    id<AGSTiledLayerTileDelegate> _tileDelegate;
    NSOperationQueue *_operationQueue;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) id<AGSTiledLayerTileDelegate> tileDelegate;

@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSOperationQueue *operationQueue;

@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) AGSTileInfo *tileInfo;

- (NSOperation<AGSTileOperation>*)retrieveImageAsyncForTile:(AGSTile*)tile;

@end



@protocol AGSTileOperation <NSObject>

@property (nonatomic, retain) AGSTile *tile;

@end
```

Based on these, I generated the following binding classes

```
[BaseType (typeof (AGSLayer))]
interface AGSTiledLayer {

    [Export ("tileDelegate")]
    AGSTiledLayerTileDelegate TileDelegate { get; set; }

    [Export ("operationQueue")]
    NSOperationQueue OperationQueue { get; }

    [Export ("tileInfo")]
    AGSTileInfo TileInfo { get; }

    [Export ("retrieveImageAsyncForTile:")]
    AGSTileOperation RetrieveImageAsyncForTile (AGSTile tile);
}

[BaseType (typeof (NSObject))]
[Model]
interface AGSTileOperationProtocol {

    [Export ("tile")]
    AGSTile Tile { get; set; }
}

[BaseType (typeof (NSOperation))]
interface AGSTileOperation : AGSTileOperationProtocol 
{}
```

When I call the `RetrieveImageAsyncForTile` with a valid `AGSTile`, it I get an `InvalidCastException` saying that it `Cannot cast from source type to destination type`. I also tried just having my AGSTileOperation functionally equivalent to the `AGSTileOperationProtocol` above, but with a `NSOperation` `BaseType`, both with and without the `[Model]`.

What is the best way to deal with method bindings such as `- (NSOperation<AGSTileOperation>*)retrieveImageAsyncForTile:(AGSTile*)tile;` ?

I tried a few alternatives similar to [Monotouch binding - "Cannot cast from source type to destination type."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13696994/monotouch-binding-cannot-cast-from-source-type-to-destination-type?rq=1), but their problem never seemed to be solved.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Update #1**

If I change the return type of the `RetrieveImageAsyncForTile` from `AGSTileOperation` to `NSOperation` it returns properly, and without fail, but missing the additional (required) property. This gave me another idea that I thought might yield some additional insight, but to my surprise, despite my thought that it couldn't possibly fail, it did.

```
[BaseType (typeof (NSOperation))]
interface AGSTileOperation
{}
```

Which I figured, since it has no additional properties or methods on top of `NSOperation`, should be equivalent, but it too yielded an `InvalidCastException`.

Hopefully someone has some idea how I can work around this?

Answer (score 1):

So it turned out that a straight binding solution didn't fix the problem, but with a suggestion from the [Xamarin Forums](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/4809/binding-a-return-type-class-that-conforms-to-a-protocol), I did manage to get it to work.

So here is the final binding I used:

```
[BaseType (typeof (AGSLayer))]
interface AGSTiledLayer {

    [Export ("tileDelegate")]
    AGSTiledLayerTileDelegate TileDelegate { get; set; }

    [Export ("operationQueue")]
    NSOperationQueue OperationQueue { get; }

    [Export ("tileInfo")]
    AGSTileInfo TileInfo { get; }

    [Export ("retrieveImageAsyncForTile:")]
    IntPtr RetrieveImageAsyncForTile (AGSTile tile);
}

[BaseType (typeof (NSOperation))]
interface AGSTileOperation {

    [Export ("tile")]
    AGSTile Tile { get; set; }
}
```

Now here's where we can use it.

```
IntPtr op = agsTiledLayer.RetrieveImageAsyncForTile(tile);
AGSTileOperation aop = new AGSTileOperation(op);
```

Of course, it's not as clean as a pure binding solution, but it solved this problem which I've been having for a week.

Comment: If you decide to stick with this solution, mark RetrieveImageAsyncForTile as `[Internal]`, and write an overload in your `Extra.cs` file, so you keep a neat API and hide your IntPtr hack.

Comment: @Jamie, How far have you gotten with your bindings? Are you willing to share or post to the Xamarin Github repo?

Comment: @ShawnKendrot: My application is only focusing on a subset of the system, so I don't have to produce bindings for the entire system. I could check with my employer about sharing the bindings (As that's really their call). In either case, ObjectiveSharpie is will get you 90% of the way there with little effort.

Answer (score 0):

I know I am 5 years late to this BUT I ran into this same problem and for anyone who comes across it - I think this is a possible solution:

The OP was on to something when he suggested this as a possible binding:

```
[BaseType (typeof (NSOperation))]
interface AGSTileOperation
{}
```

*I believe* this does not work because:

```
- (NSOperation<AGSTileOperation>*)retrieveImageAsyncForTile:(AGSTile*)tile;
```

is returning a NSOperation that conforms to AGSTileOperation (not the other way around) - Objective-C experts, call me out if I am wrong here...

With that said, the solution would be to create the following skeleton interface in the bindings:

```
[BaseType (typeof (NSOperation))]
[Protocol]
interface INSOperation : AGSTileOperation
{}
```

Which would then create what you need, of course you would need to update the return type for the original method. This worked for me in my scenario (I was dealing with `UIViewController`). I believe this would work for the OP as well - I am curious what other, more experienced, would say to this.

Answer (score -1):

May I ask what version of the ArcGIS iOS runtime you are trying to bind?  Your AGSTiledLayer interface definition looks nothing like what is in the SDK; the .h file in 10.2 only has a AGSTileInfo reference and 2 conversion methods.

I am currently trying the bind the 10.1.1/10.2 runtime after creating the binding DLL as best I could, but I cannot link the framework properly (the older sample is outdated.)  Could you please let me know what compiler flags you used in monotouch, and how you set up your Xamarin project?

Currently using XCode 4.6.2 and Xamarin Studio 4.0.8 (pretty current)

Regards,
Vernon

Comment: this doesn't look like an answer

Comment: yes, you're right, but for me there doesn't seem to be an 'Add Comment' link in the question section above.

Anyways, I have seen instances of that form when doing my own binding - I will probably encounter the same issue at some point.

Comment: Hey Vernon, I can definitely recommend some pointers. Get ObjectiveSharpie. It will get you 90% of the way on most of your bindings.

In your `linkwith.cs` try this `LinkWith`
`[assembly: LinkWith ("libArcGIS.a", LinkTarget.ArmV6 | LinkTarget.ArmV7 | LinkTarget.Simulator, IsCxx=true, ForceLoad = true, Frameworks = "CoreGraphics, CoreLocation, CoreText, Foundation, QuartzCore, MediaPlayer, MobileCoreServices, OpenGLES, Security, UIKit", LinkerFlags = "-lz -all_load -ObjC")]`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I cannot find the libArcGIS.a file in the SDK install folder; is it embedded somewhere?  From the docs, the link with.cs file won't get generated unless I add it to the project first.

Comment: If you look in ArcGIS.Framework, you will see an ArcGIS file. Make a copy of this, and rename it to libArcGIS.a.

Comment: Thanks, this works out well!  I was also able to bind ArcGIS as a framework, and use the equivalent linker flags to build the client app.

`-v -v -v -gcc_flags "-all_load -ObjC -lc++ -lz -L${ProjectDir} -F /Users/vchin/Library/SDKs/ArcGIS/iOS -framework ArcGIS -framework CFNetwork -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreLocation -framework CoreText -framework Foundation -framework QuartzCore -framework MediaPlayer -framework MobileCoreServices -framework OpenGLES -framework Security -framework UIKit"`

Please let me know if you want me to try other bindings in the future.